# How to add texture?

Tags: texturing

How to make the grid automatically overlap the texture? Manually turns crooked.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have textured model with overridden UV map. Try to restore it from source or manually tune UV map for the texture.

Comment: Hi. It would be useful if you could mention *how* the user should do any of that.